# How can I fix this expanding issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

So I'm trying to create an accordion style menu where if you click a panel it opens the section. If you click it again, it closes. On top of that, it should also close any other panel that was previously opened.

I've almost got that functionality but the problem is that I have to click it twice.

To see what I mean, check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ksu64t2/1/)

You'll notice that if you open `link one` then try to open `link 2`, you'll have to press `link 2` twice.

How can I make it so that you only have to press it once to close `link 1` but also open `link 2` ?

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle');
const handleClick = (e) => {
  const active = document.querySelector('.open');
  if(active){
    active.classList.remove('open');
  } else {
    e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.add('open')
  }
}
dropdown.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.menu {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li .dropdown {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background: grey;
}
.menu ul li .dropdown.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 3</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 4</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 5</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: removing the } else {}  : https://jsfiddle.net/9ksu64t2/2/

Comment: and if you want a toggle on the current item: https://jsfiddle.net/9ksu64t2/3/

Comment: @progysm Please add your solution as an answer. Include your fiddle but also please add the code as a stackoverflow snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use js like the following.

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle');
const handleClick = (e) => {

  const isLastOpenTargetClicked = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('open');
  
  if(isLastOpenTargetClicked) {
    e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('open');
    return;
  }
  
  const active = document.querySelector('.open');
  if(active){
    active.classList.remove('open');
  }
  
  e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.add('open')
  
}
dropdown.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.menu {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li .dropdown {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background: grey;
}
.menu ul li .dropdown.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 3</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 4</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 5</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to check whether the current element is active; On the click handler you simply want to check whether the [**`.nextElementSibling`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling)'s **[`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** **contains** the class `open`. If it does, remove it. If it doesn't, apply it.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle');
const handleClick = (e) => {
  if (e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('open')) {
    e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('open');
  } else {
    e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.classList.add('open')
  }
}
dropdown.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.menu {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul li .dropdown {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background: grey;
}

.menu ul li .dropdown.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 1</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 2</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 3</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 4</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">link 5</a>
      <div class="dropdown">Some text</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @ProEvilz -- Fixed :)

Comment: @ProEvilz this doesn't close previous opened item as requested in question?

Comment: @garyx That's because OP's edited the answer to another one that now *doesn't* work.

Answer (score -1):

Inside your click handler, loop the document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle'), remove all the open from classlist, then add open to the current target

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Why's that? Should answer always contains working code?

Comment: For a question like this, typically yes.